# Re-canning Ghee that was not strained well

Tags: storage-method, food-preservation, canning, ghee

I made Ghee and pressure canned it for long term storage. After it hardened, I noticed quite a lot of brown bits in it; I didn't strain it well.

Can I re-melt the Ghee, re-strain it and pressure can it again? It tastes fine, but it is unsightly to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are no known methods for canning dairy products (including the use of pressure canning). So re-canning is unsafe, and so is the original canning.